# Knox gateway error in topology deployment

Tags: knox-gateway

I am getting error for knox and unable to access any service ui.

> "2016-09-19 21:43:49,159 ERROR hadoop.gateway
>   (GatewayServer.java:handleCreateDeployment(479)) - Failed to deploy
>   topology nodemanagerui:
>   org.apache.hadoop.gateway.deploy.DeploymentException: Failed to
>   contribute provider. Role: iop-util Name: user-name. Please check the
>   topology for errors in name and role and that the provider is on the
>   classpath."

Nothings looks out of place to me, so far.
Just not getting anything other than admin topology war in deployment folder. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

This could most likely be because of an error in your topology file. Did you create a new topology file ? also it would be helpful if you could post your topology snippet.